# Is it possible to customize suggested edit reviews?

Tags: support, tags, review

I'm a new reviewer. Is it possible for me to filter reviews that don't exist in my tags. If not, can I customize it in any way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can customize reviews with your tags. Just go to [review page](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits), at top (next to Suggested Edit) click on filter. Here you can set maximum 3 tags filters.

> [image]

Comment: Do I need to filter each time I'm entering to the review page?

Comment: @Yosi - Nope. Your filter preference will remain until you reset it.